# FBO + RTT with multisampling and depth/stencil

Tags: opengl, glsl, fbo

I am currently rendering via FBO+RTT with MRT, and I was investigating the possibility to implement antialiasing via multisampling (instead of supersampling), but Im a bit puzzled by the specs (I refer to opengl spec 4.2 - so multisampled textures in FBO are supported) and what Ive read around.. in particular:

1)

if I got it right, I have 2 options: a) multisampling via multisampled renderbuffer(s), or b) multisampling using multisampled texture(s) (and keep on with RTT as Im doing right now), now:

do both methods produce identical output?

2)

im using RTT because I need 4 color attachements for a multipass rendering. After the first scene has been rendered to texture, that texture is then fed to different fragment shaders that access its data by a normal sampler2D.

should I use renderbuffers instead of textures, is there a way for a fragment shader to access the data of a renderbuffer?

3)

Ive read in the specs that a FBO with multisampled renderbuffers attached does not need a depth/stencil, since that information is kept in the multisampled renderbuffer(s)

does it mean that every color attachment to which a multisampled renderbuffer is attached, has its own depth/stencil?

what about multisampled textures as RT in a FBO? I dont think they store any depth/stencil information.. am I right? If I implement multisampling with a FBO+multisampled texture(s), do I still need a DEPTH_STENCIL_ATTACHMENT? if so, what about multisampling on depth?

4)

I only need 1 texture/renderbuffer to be antialiased, while another one MUST keep its jagged edges.. Ive read in the specs that with a FBO and multisampling, every renderable attached must have the same number of samples (altough may vary in size).

Is there a way to have only 1 of 2 RT multisampled? heres what the specs say concering the last param in teximage2DMultisample (fixedsampledlocation):

```
If fixedsamplelocations is TRUE, the image will use identical
sample locations and the same number of samples for all texels
in the image, and the sample locations will not depend on the
internalformat or size of the image.
```

does it mean that a multisampled texture with the sample locations fixed will keep the multisampled format but actually behave as a regular (non-multisampled) texture? (ie: every sample location will have the same value)?

Comment: after two days digging around the internet and into the specs, I guess I answered my questions.. but Id like someone to confirm: 1) yes 2) no 3) no, there is a separate multisample buffer (shared by every color attachments) if renderbuffer are used, otherwise (if only textures are used) I need a multisampled depth/stencil 4) Im going to use 2 separate FBO, une with a multisampled RB and TEX, and the second with a regular depth/stencil and texture - and no, fixedsamplelocations does not make a multisampled texture behave as if it was 0 sampled. Hope I got everything right

Comment: Ive found that I always need to setup a depth/stencil multisample buffer in order to have depth and stencil tests, semms to go against section 3.3.1 of the specs, but Ill post a separate question for this

Comment: 1) yes, rb and textures should produce identical results. 2) there actually was a way of reading back framebuffer in shader, via NV extension GL_NV_shader_framebuffer_fetch (that is for tegra, but i believe this was, at least on certain point, supported on geforce). 3) depth / stencil is needed regardless. note that only depth / color are multisampled, stencil only has 1 sample per pixel (at least on my GTX 260). 4) ï believe that without having the same multisampling on multiple attachments, the FBO will be framebuffer incomplete

Comment: after some thought, i might be wrong in 3)

Comment: TY, I solved using 2 FBOs, 1 multisampled, the other not. I go MRT on the first (it has 2 renderbuffers), and a second rendering from scratch on the second FBO gives me a not-multisampled result on the second FBO's renderbuffers/textures.

Comment: 3 - if you need depth/stencil for rendering and testing, then you must attach it. And one FBO has just one depth/stencil attachment for all your colors attachments.